# Setup a datastreaming server in processing

Tags: server, udp, client, processing, ports

I want to setup a datastreaming server in Processing, so the Client sends a String to the Server and the Server answeres it. For example Client - Server "Cupcake" then Server - Client "Cupcakce sounds funny" so the Server answeres the string. I tried this with the UDP library and opened the port on the server. But when the server had to answer the Clinet it did'nt work, because I can't open the client's ports. Any solutions?

Comment: Why don't you use `import processing.net.*`? It is a library provided by processing for networking

Comment: Also could you post what you have tried?

Comment: I also want to export my program as an android app. processing.net isn't available for android so i have to use UDP or oscp5

Comment: Then could you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need two-way communication.

**Using UDP** you would need two sketches that are both UDP servers and clients.
 e.g.

```
 sketch #1 listens on port 12000
 sketch #1 sends data on port 12001

 sketch #2 listens on port 12001
 sketch #2 sends data on port 12000
```

You can also **use TCP** sockets.
 As the Server you can use **Examples > Libraries > Network > ChatServer**
I'm surprised there's no ChatClient example, but you can get away with something like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import processing.net.*;

int port = 10002;

Client myClient;

void setup()
{
  size(400, 400);
  textFont(createFont("SanSerif", 16));
  myClient = new Client(this, "localhost", port); // Starts a client on port 10002
  background(0);
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  text("client - press ENTER to type\nconnected:"+myClient.active(), 15, 45);
}

void keyReleased() {
  if (keyCode == ENTER) {
    String message = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "message: ", "TCP Client messaging", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    println(message);
    if (myClient.active() && message != null) {
      myClient.write(message);
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** The server must be running before the client so the client can connect.

Be sure to checkout the difference between UDP and TCP protocols to work out which one makes most sense to use in your case (especially if you pan to use more clients).

Another option worth looking into is WebSockets. This would allow you to have a WebSocket server in Processing and the client could either be another Processing sketch or simply any [browser with WebSocket support](http://caniuse.com/#search=websocket)(e.g. most modern)